# Invoke root_scalar from a numba decorated function

Tags: numpy, scipy, numeric, numba

The following code fails when `find_root` is decorated with `nb.jit`. This is a toy example, but the idea is to have the ability to find the root of a scalar function (or potentially a multivariate function using `root`) for an array of values and store them in a numpy array.

Error message: `TypingError: cannot determine Numba type of <class 'function'>`

```
import numba as nb
import numpy as np
from scipy.optimize import root_scalar

a = 3.0
b = 1.0
c = -10.5

@nb.jit(nopython=True)
def f(x):
    return a*x**2 + b*x + c

@nb.jit(nopython=True)
def fprime(x):
    return 2*a*x + b

@nb.jit(nopython=True)
def fprime2(x):
    return 2*a

@nb.jit(nopython=True) # <-- Commenting this line makes the code work but it is slow
def findroot(arr): 
    for i in range(len(arr)):
        arr[i] = root_scalar(f, fprime=fprime, fprime2=fprime2, x0=0).root
        
if __name__ == '__main__':
    arr = np.zeros(20, np.float)
    
    import timeit  
    start = timeit.time.process_time()
    findroot(arr)
    end = timeit.time.process_time()
    print(end - start)
```

Comment: `root_scalar` is python code!

Comment: @hpaulj I think it's a wrapper around a numerical function written in C. That said, how do we make this work?

Comment: I'll let you dig into the `scipy` code.

Comment: @hpaulj Thanks! Your comment was so helpful. I will dig in the code.

Comment: Did you get any solutions to your question?

Comment: @lebesgue Nope, no answer

Answer (score 1):

> Invoke root_scalar from a numba decorated function

I think you would need to successfully JIT-compile `root_scalar` first, and that may take some effort. Since you are providing `fprime` and not a bracket, it's going to use [`newton`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/generated/scipy.optimize.newton.html) under the hood, so really you'd want to JIT-compile that and call it directly. But:

> ...the idea is to have the ability to find the root of a scalar function ... for an array of values and store them in a numpy array.

*That* you can already do with `newton`.

```py
import numba as nb
import numpy as np
from scipy.optimize import newton

a = 3.0
b = 1.0
c = -10.5

def f(x):
    return a*x**2 + b*x + c

def fprime(x):
    return 2*a*x + b

def fprime2(x):
    return np.full_like(x, 2*a)

x0 = 0
%timeit newton(f, x0=x0, fprime=fprime, fprime2=fprime2)
# 289 µs ± 8.27 µs per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 1000 loops each)

x0 = np.zeros(1000)
%timeit newton(f, x0=x0, fprime=fprime, fprime2=fprime2)
# 416 µs ± 13.5 µs per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 1000 loops each)
```

For a slightly more interesting example:

```py
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
x0 = np.zeros(1000)
c = np.linspace(-10.5, -1000, 1000)
root = newton(f, x0=x0, fprime=fprime, fprime2=fprime2)
plt.plot(c, root)
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks for your answer. Can we use numba though?

Comment: On your callables, yes; on `newton`, no. But as the example shows, you don't need to use Numba on the solver to speed up your loop by several orders of magnitude. If you really want to use Numba on `newton`, I think you could copy-paste it into your file and resolve any complaints that come up during JIT-compile.